# How can I sort a random word in Python based on specific criteria?

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop, while-loop

How to sort a random word by different ordering logics (criteria)?

An exercise from a book asks me to make a program that sorts the letters of a random word given certain criteria.

1. First, all the lowercase letters in ascending order, same but with uppercase letters.
2. Then with the digits (numbers I suppose) sort them by odd and even in ascending order as well.
3. Finally create a new variable to store the new word you created sorted by all the criteria above.

The book gives me and example.

> Given the word "OrDenar1234" the new world should be "aenrrDO1324"

Something to note is that I still didn't get to the functions section of the python book. So I'm trying to do it with the knowledge I have right now (variables, conditionals, loops, lists, etc.).

PD: the world is asked to the user using input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above answer is a better way of writing this program. But while starting out this was more easier to understand for me. So thought I should put it here. sort

```
s = "Test1231DEche"
lc="" # lc=[] list for sort() function
uc=""
edigits=""
odigits=""
for i in s: #iterate through string
    if(i.islower()):#check lower case
        lc+=i
    elif(i.isdigit()):
        if(int(i)%2==0):
            edigits+=i #check even digits
        else:
            odigits+=i
    elif(i.isupper()): #check uppercase
        uc+=i
lc=sorted(lc) #sorted since string, for sort() you need to make above to list
uc=sorted(uc) #uc after sort is a list you can see by printing them
edigits=sorted(edigits) #edigits.sort() for list
odigits=sorted(odigits)
print(uc)
fin = ' '.join(lc+uc+edigits+odigits) #join above list to string
print(fin)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# Take the word as input
word = input("Enter a word: ")

# Separate out the lowercase, uppercase, and digits
lowercase_letters = [char for char in word if char.islower()]
uppercase_letters = [char for char in word if char.isupper()]
digits = [char for char in word if char.isdigit()]

# Sort the lowercase and uppercase letters
lowercase_letters.sort()
uppercase_letters.sort()

# Separate and sort the odd and even digits
odd_digits = [digit for digit in digits if int(digit) % 2 != 0]
even_digits = [digit for digit in digits if int(digit) % 2 == 0]
odd_digits.sort()
even_digits.sort()

# Combine all of them to form the final string
final_word = "".join(lowercase_letters + uppercase_letters + odd_digits + even_digits)

print(final_word)
```

1. Asking the user to input for a word.
2. Break that word down into lowercase letters, uppercase letters, and digits.
3. Sort each group in ascending order.
4. Combine the sorted groups to form the final word.
5. Finally, Print the final result!!

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize the built-in string methods: `str.islower()`, `str.isupper()`, and `str.isdigit()` (I didn't use the `str.isdigit()` method because I use an `else` clause instead.

```py
s = 'OrDenar1234'
middle = ''
end = ''
start = ''
for i in sorted(s):
    if i.islower():
        start += i
    elif i.isupper():
        middle += i
    else:
        end += i
print(start + middle + end)
```

Output:

```
aenrrDO1234
```

Comment: OP wants odd digits to sort before even. So the expected output is `aenrrDO1324` rather than `aenrrDO1234`.